# Can I pass an Android.OS.Handler from c# to java?

Tags: android, xamarin, java-native-interface

I need to instantiate a java class in a .jar from c#. The java class takes an Android.OS.Handler in the constructor. I added a java bindings project  which created a wrapper for the java class. In c#, I create a Handler(Action) and pass it to the wrapper. Everything seems to "work", but the Action I passed into the Handler never gets called.

Is this passing of a Handler from c# to java supposed to work or am I trying something that won't work through JNI?

Comment: Did you try using [Register] attribute? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/limitations/#Limited_Java_Generation_Support